# problem running webpage with thymeleaf without springboot

Tags: java, maven, thymeleaf

I am building a webshop for a class assignment using maven. Currently I am trying to create a "genreOverview" page that displays books based on the genre picked by the user using thymeleaf WITHOUT SPRING. But when i start the server and try to run the page, i get the error:

```
[/WebShop23Maven_war_exploded] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect.getVariableExpressionEvaluator(StandardDialect.java:179)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect.getExecutionAttributes(StandardDialect.java:393)
        at org.thymeleaf.DialectSetConfiguration.build(DialectSetConfiguration.java:263)
        at org.thymeleaf.EngineConfiguration.<init>(EngineConfiguration.java:123)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.initialize(TemplateEngine.java:336)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1079)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1067)
        at org.chaotec.servlets.GenreOverview.doGet(GenreOverview.java:34)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

this is the thymeleafConfig:

```
package org.chaotec.thymeleaf;

import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@WebListener
public class ThymeleafConfig implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ThymeleafConfig.class.getName());
    private static TemplateEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        /* This method is called when the servlet context is initialized(when the Web application is deployed). */
        log.info("Anwendung gestartet.");
        log.info(sce.getServletContext().getServerInfo());
        engine = templateEngine(sce.getServletContext());
    }


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        /* This method is called when the servlet Context is undeployed or Application Server shuts down. */
    }
    public static TemplateEngine getTemplateEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ServletContext servletContext) {
        TemplateEngine engine = new TemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver(servletContext));
        return engine;
    }
    
    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver(ServletContext servletContext) {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(servletContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

this is my servlet (the code is not what the genreOverview should be, but an example that i use when i first learned about thymeleaf):

```
package org.chaotec.servlets;

import org.chaotec.backend.Book;
import org.chaotec.database.Database;
import org.chaotec.thymeleaf.ThymeleafConfig;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext;


import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@WebServlet(name = "GenreOverview", value = "/genreOverview")
public class GenreOverview extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        TemplateEngine engine = ThymeleafConfig.getTemplateEngine();
        WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, request.getServletContext());
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");


        context.setVariable("recipient", "World");
        List<String> staedte = new ArrayList<>();
        staedte.add("Emden"); staedte.add("Leer"); staedte.add("Aurich");
        context.setVariable("staedte", staedte);
        context.setVariable("modul",
                request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("modul"));
        engine.process("genreOverview.html", context, response.getWriter());
    }
}
```

and this is the genreOverview.html (also not the actual genreOverview page, just the example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello <span th:text="${recipient}">Peter</span>!!!</h1>
    <h2>Modul <span th:text="${modul}">Java</span></h2>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="stadt : ${staedte}" th:text="${stadt}">Berlin</li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.chaotec</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebShop23Maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.26</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

the original error i got was actually "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ognl/PropertyAccessor" but then i added the ognl dependancy i am currently stuck with this error. I've tried rerunning a clean build to even making a 1-to-1 copy of a new project but still nothing works. I only want to solve this error so i can see what my output looks like and start working on the actual page display

Comment: keep empty body `<body></body>` and check if there is any issue.

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao didn't work. still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I would use the newest versions of the frameworks:

- jakarta.servlet-api 6.0.0 (instead of outdated javax.servlet-api from 2018)
- thymeleaf 3.1.1.RELEASE
- ogn 3.3.4